# Integrating Google Analytics on an intermediary 301 going to a booking engine and coming from Flash?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a flash booking widget which I do not have the source code for, which goes to an intermediary page which should go to a booking engine ( I have not programmed it yet ).

I am looking to implement cross-domain GA tracking on the intermediary page, because I do not control the flash booking widget. It just goes to `redirect.php` with parameters that should be fed to the booking engine.

I've come across these answers:

- [HTTP Referrer on Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668773/http-referrer-on-redirection)
- [Process data BEFORE a 301 Redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954799/process-data-before-a-301-redirect)
- [track a redirect page with google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506669/track-a-redirect-page-with-google-analytics)

But there's really no definitive solution for this. Has anyone come across a similar dilemma, and if so could you share how you integrated the tracking?

Specific questions:

- The new google code uses an asynchronous method, but can I bind an event handler to invoke itself, which can do a `location.href` setting, after the page has been tracked?

Comment: edit: found some great answers @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692503/javascript-redirect-with-google-analytics/9887468#9887468 . Will test them out and will post a definitive solution if no one else does first.